# Tensorflow serving get all active models metadata in Java maven

Tags: java, tensorflow-serving

I'm looking for a way to get model metadata from all currently active models on Tensorflow Serving in Java Maven.

I have some working code for retrieving metadata from a specific model and version so if it would be possible to get a list of all model names and versions through grpc (or api) that would be great. Working code using tensorflow-client ([com.yesup.oss](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.yesup.oss/tensorflow-client)) :

```
    static ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(TF_SERVICE_HOST, TF_SERVICE_PORT)
        .usePlaintext(true).build();
    static PredictionServiceGrpc.PredictionServiceBlockingStub stub = PredictionServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);

public static void getMetadata(String model, Integer version) {

    System.out.println("Create request");
    GetModelMetadataRequest request =  GetModelMetadataRequest.newBuilder()
            .setModelSpec(ModelSpec.newBuilder()
                    .setName(model)
                    .setSignatureName("serving_default")
                    .setVersion(Int64Value.newBuilder().setValue(version))
                     )
            .addMetadataField("signature_def") 
                    .build();

    System.out.println("Collecting metadata...");
    GetModelMetadataResponse response = stub.getModelMetadata(request);
    System.out.println("Done");
    try {
        SignatureDefMap sdef = SignatureDefMap.parseFrom(
        response.getMetadataMap().get("signature_def").getValue());

       System.out.println(  sdef);
   } catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException e1) {
       e1.printStackTrace();
   }
 }
```

#### Own thoughts

I have thought about a couple of solutions, however none of them are preferable.

1. Create a server on the same device running Tensorflow Serving that can share the content of Tensorflow Serving config file. The config file contains model names and version, but we will not know if they are currently active.
2. Use jython or python to access other libraries (tensorflow-serving-api) which seems to contain "list-all-model-names" and "retriveConfig".

Any advice are appreciated, thanks in advance!